# Как в Jest + Supertest проверить, что middleware функция ExpressJS запускается и выполняется?

Tags: javascript, express, jest

Я хочу проверить, что моя middleware функция запускается и выполняется (ну или как минимум запускается). При этом, мне нужно чтобы факт проверки отразился в coverage. Но похоже, что все функции jest-объекта сделаны для mock-ов, и в итоге ничего не отображается. Даже .spyOn() нуждается в объекте, а не в функции...

Импортирую

```
const request = require('supertest');
const express = require('express');
const initMiddleware = require('../../../src/middleware/init.middleware');
```

Создаю новый сервер и подключаю middleware

```
const server = express();
server.use(initMiddleware);
```

Тестирую

```
describe('customName', () => {
  test('customName', async () => {
    await request(server).get('/').send();
    expect(initMiddleware).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // знаю, что эта функция для mock-ов : у меня вылетает ошибка
  });
});
```

Буду рад любому совету!

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос лог ошибки. Что значит « факт проверки отразился в coverage» — в таблице или просто логе или нужен тест на мидлваре?